# getchanges doesn't return the changes half the time

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, xceed

I'm using an Xceed grid bound with a `DataSet`/`DataTable`. The thing is, I need to know if changes were made before loading new datas in the grid and therefore, losing changes if I don't save them then.

But neither the `DataSet` nor `DataTable`'s function `getChanges([DataRowState])` 
return the right thing :S

I've found that sometimes `dataColumnChangeEvent` is called, but NOT `dataRowChangeEvent`, these are the times where the changes are not saved into the `getChanges()` function.

This happens when I click out of the grid while in an editing cell instead of selecting an other of the grid's cell by any way.

Also, I've looked and the `rowState` is to `Unchanged`, even if the data do is changed :S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! I've finnaly found a solution.

Even if the dataRowChangeEvent doesn't seem to be called (I'll explain latter)

If the only code in the rowChangeEvent is the code below it works :

```
Private Sub RowChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged Then
        e.Row.AcceptChanges()
        e.Row.SetModified()
    End If
End Sub
```

We check the rowState because we can only setModified() a row wit the Unchanged state.

We do AcceptChanges() because doing only setModified() removes the changes on the edited cell.

We do SetModified(0 because if not AcceptChanges() leaves the RowState to Unchanged and therefor it doesn't get in the table's getChanges.

EDIT : This brings an other problem, the dataAdapter uses the datarow's original and current Value to do update, delete and insert, 
doing "acceptChanges" set OriginalValue to the current Value so delete and Update doesn't work anymore :(

--More--

When I said it doesn't seem to get in the event, it's because the code below :

```
Private Sub RowChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged Then
        e.Row.AcceptChanges()
        e.Row.SetModified()
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("hasError=" & IIf(e.Row.HasErrors, "true ", "false ") & _
                    "; action=" & e.ProposedValue)
End Sub
```

neither Shows the message Box nor get the changes in the dataTable's getChanges()...

Also, having only

```
MessageBox.Show("Changing")
```

instead of the previons messageBox, Do show the messageBox, and Do get the changes right, BUT it then kindof breaks the event so it doesn't go further in the newProjectSelected => no new project is loaded, but it only needs a "re-clic".

So, I've explained how it behaves.

But it's soo strange, I'de appreciate if someone would explaine shuch behaviour.